# I’m running PHP on Windows and get the error "No such file or directory"

Tags: php, cmd

There are similar questions on this site, but none have this same problem that I can find. I run PHP by going to cmd and typing:

```
php -S localhost:4000"
```

But when I go to "localhost:4000/www/site.php" it says that it can’t be found, but I have checked three times, and it is correct. It was working yesterday, I changed nothing and now it’s not working.

The directory is: *C:\Users\Spencer\www\site.php*

*$_ENV['USERPROFILE'] => C:\Users\Spencer*

How can I fix it?

The output is:

> [Mon Aug  8 17:55:38 2022] PHP 8.1.9 Development Server (http://localhost:4000) started
>
> [Mon Aug  8 17:59:59 2022] [::1]:62146 Accepted
>
> [Mon Aug  8 17:59:59 2022] [::1]:62146 [404]: GET /www/site.php - No such file or directory
>
> [Mon Aug  8 17:59:59 2022] [::1]:62146 Closing

Comment: From what directory are you starting the build-in server?

Comment: post the output of `dir /s /b && php -S localhost:4000`

Comment: How do you "go to 'localhost:4000/www/site.php'", exactly?

Comment: i've voted to close this question as "Needs debugging details" - specifically it needs the output of `dir /s /b && php -S localhost:4000` to debug your issue. add that to your post and i'll consider retracting my close vote. (my best guess is that you're simply starting php from the wrong folder. dir with the correct arguments would prove/disprove my theory.)

Comment: @TimRoberts I am using google chrome

Comment: @GuidoFaecke It doesnt say

Comment: @hanshenrik How do I convert the output of cmd into a file, it gave me about a thousand lines, is there a specific one you need?

Comment: @EnderPrince just upload the file to https://pastebin.com/ (they support file uploads) and post the link to it.

Comment: Ive added the simple output after the started line.

Comment: @hanshenrik I cant get it to output to a folder, I have tried adding > C:\output.txt
to the end, and all it does is make a blank page instead of the output, I gtg for an couple hours, ill try more when I get home

Comment: @EnderPrince do you have netcat installed? in which case run: `dir /s /b | nc termbin.com 9999` - if you don't have netcat, do you have pastebinit installed? in which case run `dir /s /b | pastebinit` - or do you have neither netcat nor pastebinit installed? run `dir /s /b > foo.txt` then upload foo.txt to pastebin.com in your browser.

Comment: Have you tried just loading `localhost:4000/site.php` ? I'd assume your document root is `www` but it's hard to tell with this information.

Comment: You must "cd \Users\Spencer` before starting PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command))'ing into the `\Users\Spencer` directory before starting PHP solves the problem.